# Questions are not lined up vertically

Tags: bug, design

Some questions, at least on meta, are further to the right than others:

> [image: screen shot with lines added to show spacing]
>
> (Firefox 62.0.2 on Windows 10)

In this screen shot, I added red lines to try to show how the columns don't always line up.  At first I thought the question title had a space at the beginning, but then I noticed the tags were also further to the right, and in fact the other columns aren't lined up properly either.

It doesn't look very good.

-additional from user3169-

I see it too. Firefox 62.0.2 on Windows 7 -
[image: screenshot showing misaligned questions]

-additional from ColleenV

I don't see it in Firefox on my iMac, but I do in Firefox on Windows. I also see horizontal alignment issues.

[image: screenshot showing misaligned questions]

---

EDIT 2018-10-13: With the new design, things seem somewhat better, but they still aren't lined up quite right:

> [image: vertical alignment in new design]

Comment: I see it on Firefox Developer for Windows 63.0b8 as well. The horizontal problem seems to appear when there are multiple answers and one of them is accepted. This makes the label text wider both because of the extra letter and because the line is boldfaced. Ordinary `<div class="answered">` renders at about 44px wide on my screen, but `<div class="answered-accepted">` is about 49px wide. The same set of styles affects the vertical alignment, since `.answer-accepted .mini-counts` pushes things around with relative positioning whereas the regular mini-counts just use bottom margin.

Comment: I do see the horizontal alignment issue on my Mac, just not the vertical one. Weird. Maybe the differences in fonts affects the vertical alignment.